# MSVCP80.dll is missing at VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010) Ultimate. After installing SP1 for the VS2010. My projects can't run for the release mode (Debug mode is fine) and the error is "The program can't start because MSVCP80.dll is missing". Where can I get MSVCP80.dll for my VS2010 and how to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215143/the-program-cant-start-because-msvcp80-dll-is-missing

Comment: It is a support library for code that was compiled with VS2005.  This does not have anything to do with installing SP1.  You must recompile *all* of the libraries you use with VS2010.

Comment: No it used to work before I install SP1to my VS2010 ultimate. but after installing SP1, I got that problem.