# how to determine whether installed library is 32 bit or 64 bit on windows?

Tags: dll

How to determine whether library is 32 bit or 64 bit from the library file ? I have installed gstreamer from ossbuild for this I know its 32 bit but suppose if someone else installs a library what is the way to find if it is compatible with 32bit or 64bit . Also are the format of the library similar or they differ?

Answer (score 0):

When you said "Library", I guess you mean "runtime Library" aka. Dynamic-Link Library (DLL), is that correct?

In that case, this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495244/how-can-i-test-a-windows-dll-to-determine-if-it-is-32bit-or-64bit)

Comment: Maybe when he says "library" he means "library" - as in .lib files?