# How to check whether installed OpenCV is 64-bit or 32-bit?

Tags: c++, opencv

How do I check whether a 64-bit or 32-bit OpenCV is installed?

I am using VC++ 2010, 32-bit build.

Comment: it might be helpful to state which platform you are using?

Comment: i am using VC++ 2010, 32 bit build ..

Comment: You will probably find your answer [in this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495244/how-can-i-test-a-windows-dll-to-determine-if-it-is-32bit-or-64bit).  I hope this helps you out!

Comment: but i want to check only the library , opencv is 32 bit or 64 version

Comment: Did you ever find a simple answer?