# Error 193 when loading a DLL with Python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

We are trying to connect to an external piece of hardware using a DLL and faced a problem we were not able to solve so far. Our platform is Windows 7, 64 bit, and we are using Python 2.7, also 64 bit, to write a driver. The DLL we are using is also 64 bit (we double checked that with the [PE Deconstructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495244/how-can-i-test-a-windows-dll-to-determine-if-it-is-32bit-or-64bit)). We use ctypes to load the DLL, specifically:

```
import ctypes

ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('dllpath')

...
```

However, we get the error message `[Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`. The same happens if we try to load 32 bit DLLs or use the commands `pydll`, `oledll` or `windll`. Do you have an idea how we could load the DLL or what the solution might be?

We would be very grateful for a helpful answer,

Best, Florian

Comment: Is your python.exe visible in system variables path?

Comment: Sounds like a bitness mismatch. Either in the DLL or its dependencies. Check using Dependency Viewer, for instance.

Comment: `cdll` and `windll` are loaders that wrap `CDLL` and `WinDLL`, to cache loaded libraries and make it easy to access Windows DLLs when the base filename is a syntactically valid identifier, e.g. `cdll.msvcr100`. The `LoadLibrary` method just calls the wrapped class and doesn't cache the library, so you may as well use `ctypes.CDLL('dllpath')`.

Comment: As to loading the DLL, there's no difference between `CDLL` and `WinDLL`. The latter just sets a flag on function pointers to use `stdcall` instead of `cdecl`. In 64-bit Windows there's no difference anyway since there's only one standard calling convention for exported functions.

Comment: Are all the dependencies present? If the DLL requires other DLLs to operate that may be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 32 bit and 64 bit.  I did the same, Win 7 64 bit, Python 64 bit, but a third party hardware dll 32 bit.  Answer, remove Python 64 bit, install Python 32 bit.  A good discussion here: https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/789333-ctypes-64-bit-windows-32-bit-dll