# How can I detect, programmatically, whether a DLL is compiled 32bit or 64bit in .NET?

Tags: c++, .net, dll

So far I have been able to load the dll using the following code:

```
Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::LoadFrom(pathDll);
```

But I don't know how to detect whether it's 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test a windows dll to determine if it is 32bit or 64bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495244/how-can-i-test-a-windows-dll-to-determine-if-it-is-32bit-or-64bit)

Comment: You can use dumpbin utli syntax : dumpbin /headers <dll name>

Answer (score 1):

I think that I've found the answer. Off course, first of all you must get the assembly associated with the dll though the following line of code:

```
Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::LoadFrom(pathDll);
```

Then you can get the information about the platform through the following code:

```
ProcessorArchitecture processor_architecture = assembly->GetName()->ProcessorArchitecture;
        if (ProcessorArchitecture::Amd64 == processor_architecture)
        {
            // 64bits
        }
        if (ProcessorArchitecture::X86 == processor_architecture)
        {
            //32 bits
        }
```