# Win32 API to tell whether a given binary (EXE or DLL) is x86, x64, or ia64

Tags: windows, winapi, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am trying to find a programmatic way to tell if a binary is x86, x64, or ia64.

Platform: Windows.
Language: c/c++.

Background: Before trying to load a third-party dll, I need to find out its bitness.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find if native dll is compiled as x64 or x86?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480696/how-to-find-if-native-dll-is-compiled-as-x64-or-x86)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### For EXEs

use [GetBinaryType(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364819(VS.85).aspx)

[Here is same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197951/how-can-i-determine-for-which-platform-an-executable-is-compiled/198009) for manged exe.

### For DLLs (and EXEs)

Use the [ImageNtHeader(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680212(VS.85).aspx) to get the PE data of the file and then check the IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Machine field.

[Here is some code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#RRljDOJ5z1I/dyninstAPI-4.0.3/core/dyninstAPI/src/Object-nt.C&q=ImageNtHeader%20lang:c%2B%2B&l=641) I found using Google Code Search

**No Cleanup and NO error checking**

```
// map the file to our address space
// first, create a file mapping object
hMap = CreateFileMapping( 
  hFile, 
  NULL,           // security attrs
  PAGE_READONLY,  // protection flags
  0,              // max size - high DWORD
  0,              // max size - low DWORD      
  NULL );         // mapping name - not used

// next, map the file to our address space
void* mapAddr = MapViewOfFileEx( 
  hMap,             // mapping object
  FILE_MAP_READ,  // desired access
  0,              // loc to map - hi DWORD
  0,              // loc to map - lo DWORD
  0,              // #bytes to map - 0=all
  NULL );         // suggested map addr

peHdr = ImageNtHeader( mapAddr );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like that particular API is going to just fail for .dll.

Answer (score 2):

I open-sourced [a project on Github that checks for VC++ redistributable DLLs](https://github.com/markedup-mobi/crt-detector) specifically and there's a code snippet I created based off of the function in Shay's answer that [successfully finds, loads, and inspects DLLs for x86 / x64 compatibility](https://github.com/markedup-mobi/crt-detector/blob/master/VCRuntimeDetector/VCDetector.cpp#L118).

Full code snippet below:

```
/******************************************************************
Function Name:  CheckProductUsingCurrentDirectory
Description:    Queries the current working directory for a given binary.
Inputs:         pszProductFolderToCheck - the product name to look up.
pBinaryArchitecture - the desired processor architecture
of the binary (x86, x64, etc..).
Results:        true if the requested product is installed
false otherwise
******************************************************************/
bool CheckProductUsingCurrentDirectory(const LPCTSTR pszProductBinaryToCheck, Architecture pBinaryArchitecture){
        bool bFoundRequestedProduct = false;

        //Get the length of the buffer first
        TCHAR currentDirectory[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD currentDirectoryChars = GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, currentDirectory);

        //exit if couldn't get current directory
        if (currentDirectoryChars <= 0) return bFoundRequestedProduct;

        TCHAR searchPath[MAX_PATH];
        //exit if we couldn't combine the path to the requested binary
        if (PathCombine(searchPath, currentDirectory, pszProductBinaryToCheck) == NULL) return bFoundRequestedProduct;

        WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
        HANDLE hFind= FindFirstFile(searchPath, &FindFileData);

        //exit if the binary was not found
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return bFoundRequestedProduct;

        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(searchPath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, NULL);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) goto cleanup;

        HANDLE hMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY | SEC_IMAGE, 0, 0, pszProductBinaryToCheck);
        if (hMapping == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) goto cleanup;

        LPVOID addrHeader = MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
        if (addrHeader == NULL) goto cleanup; //couldn't memory map the file

        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS peHdr = ImageNtHeader(addrHeader);
        if (peHdr == NULL) goto cleanup; //couldn't read the header

        //Found the binary, AND its architecture matches. Success!
        if (peHdr->FileHeader.Machine == pBinaryArchitecture){
                bFoundRequestedProduct = true;
        }

cleanup: //release all of our handles
        FindClose(hFind);
        if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                CloseHandle(hFile);
        if (hMapping != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                CloseHandle(hMapping);
        return bFoundRequestedProduct;
}
```

This question and Shay's answer were helpful to me while I was creating this, so I thought I'd post the project here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the PE header yourself to read the `IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE` field.  [Here's a C# implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001404/check-if-unmanaged-dll-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/1002672#1002672) that shouldn't be too hard to adapt to C++.