# Programatically determine if native .exe is 32-bit or 64-bit

Tags: c++, windows, 32bit-64bit, wow64

I need to know whether a given .exe is 32-bit or a 64-bit, *before* I launch it. `IsWow64Process` is no use here, since there is no process yet. Is there some other API that will give me this information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find if native dll is compiled as x64 or x86?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480696/how-to-find-if-native-dll-is-compiled-as-x64-or-x86)

Comment: Actually, I withdraw the dup - this is a lot easier for EXEs than for DLLs, it seems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really only  want to do this for EXEs and not DLLs, just use [GetBinaryType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364819(VS.85).aspx).

> Determines whether a file is an
>   executable (.exe) file, and if so,
>   which subsystem runs the executable
>   file.

Comment: Yes, this is *exactly* what I want, and it's much easier than reading the PE header myself, which is what the other answers suggested. Thanks.

Comment: You are lucky you just need EXEs :-)  Those complex contortions appear necessary to do this for DLLs.  A gap in Win32, imo.

Answer (score 5):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001404/check-if-unmanaged-dll-is-32-bit-or-64-bit) will surely help you.

Is C# related but it will give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This information is available in one of the headers of the [PE File file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) (the format used for exe's and dll's). The information in these headers can either be extracted programmatically (they are at a specified offset) or more safely queried via the Win32 API.

Alright, Liviu got the correct pointer for you.