# How to detect that a given PE file (exe or dll) is 64 bit or 32 bit

Tags: c++, winapi, x86, 64-bit

I need to detect whether a given .dll or .exe file is 32 bit or 64 bit

At the moment I have only one solution: read the PE Header from the specified file and take the 'Machine' field from there.

( Specification: [Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/pecoff_v8.docx) (.docx file) at section "3.3. COFF File Header (Object and Image)" )

This field can take up to about 20 values. Three of them are:

```
IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386  ( == 32bit )

IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64  ( == 64bit )

IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 ( == 64bit )
```

My questions:

1) Is 'Machine' to bitness mapping correct or did I miss something? Are there any other caveats?

2) Is there easier way to detect 32/64 bitness (probably some specific field in PE format I didn't notice or some special system function)?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971689/win32-api-to-tell-whether-a-given-binary-exe-or-dll-is-x86-x64-or-ia64/971715#971715

Comment: That other question is asking about architecture, this one is asking about word size.

Comment: Documentation is updated from v8 to v11 as of now in 2017: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[GetBinaryType(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364819(VS.85).aspx) returns `SCS_32BIT_BINARY` for a 32-bit Windows-based application
and `SCS_64BIT_BINARY` for a 64-bit Windows-based application.

Comment: This unfortunately returns 0 when analyzing a DLL.

Comment: Made it in Python: import win32file; print win32file.GetBinaryType("myfile.exe"). This returns 0 for 32bits exe or 6 for 64 bits file.

Comment: This function fails when loading a non-matching arch (e.g. 64-bit DLL in 32-bit program).

Answer (score 3):

Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Look for "Magic" member - you can find out whether PE header is 32 bit(PE32) or 64 bit(PE32+).