# How can I identify if a .exe file is 32-bit or 64-bit from C#

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit, portable-executable

How can I determine if an .EXE file (not my application, not another running application, not a .NET application) is 32-bit or 64-bit in C#? The best I found [is this](http://zuga.net/articles/cs-how-to-determine-if-a-program-process-or-file-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/#getbinarytype) and I'm guessing there's a native .NET call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect that a given PE file (exe or dll) is 64 bit or 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153090/how-to-detect-that-a-given-pe-file-exe-or-dll-is-64-bit-or-32-bit)

Comment: @GSerg Yes, that references the same link I have in my question. If that's the best way, it works. But I'm asking to find out if there's a native .NET way to do this.

Comment: I don't see that link mentioned in that question.

Comment: @GSerg The link you provided has a link to the same Windows call that  http://zuga.net/articles/cs-how-to-determine-if-a-program-process-or-file-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/#getbinarytype uses.

Comment: Microsoft implemented PEFile class in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/ and that can be used to check fitness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use third-party libraries or winAPI, here's a method that reads the header and gets the information.

```
enum PlatformFile : uint
        {
            Unknown = 0,
            x86 = 1,
            x64 = 2
        }
        static PlatformFile GetPlatformFile(string filePath)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                fs.Seek(0x3C, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                int peOffset = br.ReadInt32();
                fs.Seek(peOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                uint peHead = br.ReadUInt32();

                if (peHead != 0x00004550)
                    return PlatformFile.Unknown;

                fs.Seek(peOffset + 4, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                ushort machine = br.ReadUInt16();

                if (machine == 0x014c) // IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386
                    return PlatformFile.x86;
                else if (machine == 0x8664) // IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64 or IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64
                    return PlatformFile.x64;
                else
                    return PlatformFile.Unknown;
            }
        }
```