# How do I determine whether an application I am installing is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: x86, x86-64, executable, 32bit-64bit

I want to be able to predict the default install location of an application. On a 64-bit machine, if it is a 32-bit application, it would install in "Program Files (x86)" and if it were a 64-bit application, it would install in "Program Files".

My goal is to install the application with its default location and validate if the install was fine. But for this I need to know where it would be installed. If I know what architecture the application is built for, I think it would serve my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use external tools then [GNU `file`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) is the most versatile solution. But it might be a bit overkill for this purpose. Other alternatives being [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), Sysinternals' [Sigcheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck), MSVC's dumpbin or corflags... But the one that might surprise a lot of people is [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). It has a small `file`-like utility inside that can be used with `l` option

```
C:\>7z l "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Photo Viewer\ImagingDevices.exe" | findstr CPU
CPU = x86

C:\>7z l "C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\ImagingDevices.exe" | findstr CPU
CPU = x64
```

---

If you have to check it yourself then read 2 bytes at offset 0x3C in the file. Then add 4 to this value and read 2 bytes at that offset, that'll indicate the architecture. For example in the below example the file contains 0x00E0 at offset 0x3C. At offset 0x00E0 + 4 = 0x00E4 contains **0x8664** which means a 64-bit binary. If it was a 32-bit x86 binary then it will contain **0x014C**

[image: PE file opened as text]

There are more ways that you can find in the below links. There are also other PowerShell and VBS scripts available for that purpose

- [How can I test a Windows DLL file to determine if it is 32 bit or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495244/995714)
- [How can I determine for which platform an executable is compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197951/995714)
- [Check if exe is 64-bit](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6040/2563)
- [How to check if a binary is 32 or 64 bit on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/358434/241386)
- [10 Ways to Determine if Application is Compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/determine-application-compiled-32-64-bit/)

Answer (score 1):

Download `file` for Windows to check the details of any file on Windows:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

Then, via the Windows command line:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\file" name-of-file.exe
name-of-file.exe executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit
```

You should be able to grab the return value of this command from whatever development platform  your working with.

Comment: Thanks. But for a microsoft installer package (.msi) that I use for installation, it does not return anything except -- "Microsoft Office Document".