# How to use output from SigCheck to make conditional statment using batch?

Tags: batch-file, conditional-statements

I am using Sigcheck to check the MachineType of an exe file (MSACCESS.EXE)

*If Sigcheck says the MachineType of an exe is 32-bit GOTO ...*

*If Sigcheck says the MachineType of an exe is 64-bit GOTO ...*

**How can this be written? The output from Sigcheck.exe in the terminal is:**

```
 c:\program files (x86)\microsoft office\office16\MSACCESS.EXE:
```

> ```
>     Verified:       Signed
>     Signing date:   9:51 AM 1/23/2019
>     Publisher:      Microsoft Corporation
>     Company:        Microsoft Corporation
>     Description:    Microsoft Access
>     Product:        Microsoft Office 2016
>     Prod version:   16.0.4813.1000
>     File version:   16.0.4813.1000
>     MachineType:    32-bit
> ```

**UPDATE:**

[This is the output I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaIwA.png)

**More Details:**

Using Sigcheck.exe

I first run the following my batch script:

```
@echo off
sigcheck.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE"
```

Followed by what you said:

```
Set TestPath=%1
for /F "delims=" %%l in ('sigcheck %TestPath%^|findstr MachineType') do set ArchLine=%%l

if not "%ArchLine%"=="%ArchLine:64=%" echo The file is 64bit
if not "%ArchLine%"=="%ArchLine:32=%" echo The file is 32bit
```

**There can't ever be two responses 32/64bit as I'm only pointing to 1 file.**

So in this case it should only say *"The file is 32bit"*

**UPDATE 2:**

```
@echo off

sigcheck.exe "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft office\root\office16\MSACCESS.EXE"

Set TestPath=%1

:: See if sigcheck is in the path
where sigcheck.exe 2>NUL 1>NUL
if not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo sigcheck.exe is not in your path && PAUSE

:: Make sure the file exists
if not exist "%TestPath%" echo %TestPath% does not exist && PAUSE

for /F "delims=" %%l in ('sigcheck %TestPath%^|findstr MachineType') do set ArchLine=%%l

if not "%ArchLine%"=="%ArchLine:n/a=%" echo Not an executable file && PAUSE
if not "%ArchLine%"=="%ArchLine:64=%" echo 64bit
if not "%ArchLine%"=="%ArchLine:32=%" echo 32bit
```

**The following is the full response I get:**

> ```
> Sigcheck v2.72 - File version and signature viewer Copyright (C)
> 2004-2019 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>
>
> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft office\root\office16\MSACCESS.EXE:
>
>     Verified:       Signed
>     Signing date:   6:18 AM 3/6/2019
>     Publisher:      Microsoft Corporation
>     Company:        Microsoft Corporation
>     Description:    Microsoft Access
>     Product:        Microsoft Office
>     Prod version:   16.0.11328.20158
>     File version:   16.0.11328.20158
>     MachineType:    32-bit  does not exist Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
I have removed the stuff for you to figure out.

```
@echo off

:: Assign the first parameter passed to this batch file to the 
:: following variable.  This batch NEEDs something to look up.
Set PEBinaryPath=%~1

:: Make sure the caller passed at least one command line parameter.
if "%PEBinaryPath%"=="" (
    echo %~nx0 requires one parameter.  
    echo This parameter is the path to a PE binary to check for compiled architecture.
    echo Ie. %~nx0 "%windir%\Sytem32\notepad.exe"
    goto :EOF
)

:: See if sigcheck is in the path
where sigcheck.exe 2>NUL 1>NUL
if not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo sigcheck.exe is not in your path&& goto :EOF

:: Make sure the file exists
if not exist "%PEBinaryPath%" echo %PEBinaryPath% does not exist&& goto :EOF

:: Take the output from sigcheck, parse it and put it into a variable called MachineTypeLine
for /F "delims=" %%l in ('sigcheck "%PEBinaryPath%"^|findstr MachineType') do set MachineTypeLine=%%l

:: See if the line contains "n/a", 64, or 32
if not "%MachineTypeLine%"=="%MachineTypeLine:n/a=%" echo Not a PE format binary file&& goto :EOF
if not "%MachineTypeLine%"=="%MachineTypeLine:64=%"  echo 64bit
if not "%MachineTypeLine%"=="%MachineTypeLine:32=%"  echo 32bit
```

Results:

```
  C:\>test.bat
  test.bat requires one parameter.
  This parameter is the path to a PE binary to check for compiled architecture.
  Ie. test.bat "C:\WINDOWS\Sytem32\notepad.exe"

  C:\>test.bat c:\windows\system.ini
  Not an executable file

  C:\>test.bat c:\bobs\yeruncle.exe
  c:\bobs\yeruncle.exe does not exist

  C:\>test.bat c:\windows\System32\notepad.exe
  64bit

  C:\>test.bat c:\windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe
  32bit
```

### How does it work??

- **For /F** runs a command and puts the things it finds into a variable.
- The /F command run is ***sigcheck*** but I pipe the results to ***findstr*** to do most of the parsing for me.  We don't HAVE to do it this way but it sure is a ***whole lot*** easier becuase it only gives me lines back that contain the word "*MachineType*"
- The resulting variable (***ArchLine***) looks like (including the spaces)

> ```
>     MachineType:    64-bit
> ```

- I then use string substitution to tell if what I am looking for is in the string.  This is kind of a hack but works.  I replace "64" with NOTHING and compare it to the original string.  If the string is the same, it didn't have 64 in it!

Good luck!

Comment: I just tested your code, the output is showing both echo The file is 64bit and echo The file is 32bit

Comment: Just updated my answer with the output I am getting with your code

Comment: It works for me.. updated my answer with expected output.  Try running only the sigcheck <file>|findstr MachineType to see what you get?? If it doesn't make sense.. try running it with the @echo off removed and see what it is doing .

Comment: Ok I’ll let you know

Comment: I have tried to run it without echo off with no luck, I updated my post, please take a look. I just want to make sure we are on the same page.

Comment: In fact when the script fails (no .exe is found) it still shows both.

Comment: How could this be?

Comment: I would suggest directly before the loop, `Set "ArchLine="` and directly after the loop, `If Not Defined ArchLine Exit /B` or similar.

Comment: Man I love that @Compo guy!  Added the checks that I said were for you.  Please take some time to UNDERSTAND what I posted.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd additionally suggest looking at the `-e`, _(checks executable files only)_,  `-q` and `-r` options, and ask Winston to consider parsing the output from the `-c` option instead.

Comment: @Compo is absolutely right.  I didn't want to spend time figuring out the command line for sigcheck.exe... I was lazy and it worked.

Comment: @Compo I appreciate your comments and have implemented them, do you have any suggestion about the concerns I had with the script? Why does it keep showing 64bit and 32bit for every .exe? Shouldn’t it only show the one that Sigcheck shows?

Comment: Ok, so I've been playing around with the code and reading some documentation. I finally got the batch to give me one answer. But that answer is always "does not exist" I am a little confused on how we're using TestPath. I posted an update, please have a look.

Comment: You have to pass your batch the path to the thing you are trying to look up.  I added a check for this and changed the names of the variables I was using to clarify what the purpose is.