# Determine if an executable is 64-bit or 32-bit in C#

Tags: c#, .net, header, 64-bit, exe

I'm looking for a solution to determine whether a given executable is 64-bit or 32-bit.

The executable being tested may be .NET based or not.

I've seen multiple different techniques, not sure in what one differs from the other.

Techniques i've seen listed:

- Using dumpbin.exe (comes with Visual Studio or Windows SDK)
- Win32 function GetBinaryType http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364819(v=vs.85).aspx
- Checking the file's headers (demonstrated in this Q: [How can I determine for which platform an executable is compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197951/how-can-i-determine-for-which-platform-an-executable-is-compiled))

What is the most robust way of doing it ?

Comment: Why are you asking for a robust way - either they works or they don't, right ??

Comment: read this 

http://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows


hope this helps you

Comment: There is no reliable way to do this for a .NET executable.  AnyCPU means what it says, it can be either.  The bitness is determined at runtime.

Comment: But it is possible to know whether a compiled program has been forced to run either 32 or 64 architecture.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I know of:
 1. If you need to check it in run-time: use IsWow64Process.
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139(v=vs.85).aspx?ppud=4
    if it is a x86 process - it will return true, otherwise - false.
 2. If you need to check it not in run-time, just inspect the EXE PE format.
    if the NT Header -> Optional header->Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC 
    it's a x64 exe/dll.