# How to parse EXE file and get data from IMAGE_DOS_HEADER structure using c++ and Window.h?

Tags: c++, parsing, portable-executable

I am trying to parse PE file in windows and get data from this structure

[image: IMAGE_DOS_HEADER]

I wrote this code, that reads bytes from exe file.

```
 #include <Windows.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        // open the file for binary reading
        std::ifstream file;
            file.open("D:/SomeProgram.exe", ios_base::binary);
    
        if (!file.is_open())
            return 1;
    
        // get the length of the file
        file.seekg(0, ios::end);
        size_t fileSize = file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    
        // create a vector to hold all the bytes in the file
        std::vector<byte> data(fileSize, 0);
    
        // read the file
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data[0]), fileSize);
```

I have no idea, how to get data, that contains `e_magic`, `e_cbip`, `e_cp` .... and the most important `e_ifanew`.
I know, that this structure IMAGE_DOS_HEADER is stored in Windows.h, but I don't know how to use it to get fields from any exe file.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: [PE format is described on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: hey, I saw it on MSDN, but how can I get specific field, for example, I want, that my program shows this:
e_magic: MZ
e_cbip: P
........
e_ifnew: 00000100

Comment: Read into the structure rather than a vector.

Comment: Most efficient is to use memory mapped file and just cast pointer to the data structures you need to read. Matt Pietrek shows how to do it in his old but still relevant article ["Peering Inside the PE"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) (Table 1. PEDUMP.C). His article is also more readable than the MSDN pages linked above.

Comment: Although it's possible, I would avoid reading the entire file to a buffer if only the header is wanted. Instead you should create an instance `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER idh` and `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&idh), sizeof idh)` only the few required bytes.

Comment: @zett42, That's a performance penalty. What is EXE if a setup file of size 500+ MB? Reading just first few bytes (1K) is enough!

Comment: @Ajay Memory mapping does not read in the file at once. It only reads what you actually access. Say you map 500+ MB and read only byte at offset 500, then only first 4k (page size) of file be read.

Comment: @zett42, Reading 4K bytes it too much. Also, our performance analysis has shown that ReadFile approach is way faster than mapping. Mapped pointer access would cause a page fault (kernel trip), and eventually has to call ReadFile. See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3827bbbd-9a5d-4dc8-948e-188846ffe89f/why-file-mapping-slower-than-readfile-via-io-?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an instance of the structure and copy the data into it:

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER idh;

if ( fileSize >= sizeof(idh) )
{
    std::memcpy(&idh, &data[0], sizeof(idh));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Find below process to get data from different headers :

```
LPCSTR fileName; //exe file to parse
HANDLE hFile; 
HANDLE hFileMapping;
LPVOID lpFileBase;
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS peHeader;

hFile = CreateFileA(fileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("\n CreateFile failed in read mode \n");
    return 1;
}

hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL);

if(hFileMapping==0)
{
    printf("\n CreateFileMapping failed \n");
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}

lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0);

if(lpFileBase==0)
{
    printf("\n MapViewOfFile failed \n");
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}

dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) lpFileBase;  //pointer to dos headers

if(dosHeader->e_magic==IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
{
    //if it is executable file print different fileds of structure
    //dosHeader->e_lfanew : RVA for PE Header
    printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Matched");

    //pointer to PE/NT header
    peHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((u_char*)dosHeader+dosHeader->e_lfanew);

    if(peHeader->Signature==IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        printf("\n PE Signature (PE) Matched \n");
        //important fileds
        //peHeader->FileHeader : Refrence to FileHeader
        //peHeader->OptionalHeader :  Refrence to Optional Header
        // lots of imprtant fileds are present in File header and Optional header to retrive code/data/different sections address of exe

    }

    UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileBase);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Not Matched \n");
    UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileBase);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the file into buffer and cast part of it as structs.

```
// READ FILE ASSUMING IT EXISTS AND IS A VALID PE FILE
char* buffer = nullptr;
std::ifstream infile("C:\\file.exe", std::ios::binary);

std::filebuf* pbuf = infile.rdbuf();

size_t size = pbuf->pubseekoff(0, infile.end, infile.in);

buffer = new char[size];

pbuf->pubseekpos(0, infile.in);
pbuf->sgetn(buffer, size);

infile.close();

// CAST
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* MS_DOS = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)buffer;
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* PE = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((DWORD)buffer + MS_DOS->e_lfanew);

// DO YOUR STUFF
// ...

delete[] buffer;
```